# Intellj not creating gradle wrapper properties

Tags: java, gradle

**Issue:**

I'm using Intellj to make a Kotlin project with openJDK 14. Upon completion of the project wizard, the IDE tells me `Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found`. A gradle-wrapper.properies file is not found- it seems to me like it's not created. If I pick a JDK for Gradle to use anyway, an error like this will happen `Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache`

Why does Intellj screw up the gradle build?

**Current Fix**

I can cd into the folder after this and manually create the wrapper with `gradle wrapper`. This will create the gradle-wrapper.properties file and the build will then work.

**Assumptions**

I have gradle 6.5 installed and Intellj projects can be created without gradle. I'm using Intellj out of the box.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use gradle init command to create gradale-wrapper if it's not automatically added. Follow the link below for more details

https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/

[image: gradle init]

Comment: Thank you Arpan. I know that I can use gradle on the command line to build but I'm really trying to figure out why Intellj is not doing it for me. Something is messed up on Intellj side where it does not build gradle because it doesn't make the .properties file.